# Need help on tabs with Activities with Inheritance

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I am working on an Android project.  In my app,I have 3 tabs.  As the Activities I use have many things in common (e.g. ListView), I use inheritance as below: [image]

List a is generated by my SAXHandler and it creates a new list in startDocument ().

I have a testcase of which the list in A_Activity has 7 items and B_Activity has 3 items.  When my app starts, I have no problem clicking on all the items shown in A_Activity.  After I click B_Activity and switch back to A_Activity, I also don't have any problem clicking on the first 3 items; however, if I click on the fourth items, I get

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
```

If I increase the number of items on B_Activity to 4, I get the same exception with 3 replaced with 4.  So, I am certain that the cause of it is that when I jump back to A_Activity from B_Activity, the list in A_Activity is still referring to B_Activity's.

Your advise will be highly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: how would create the instance of MyActivity into another activity

Comment: Thanks Pratik.  I suppose you mean "how *about*".  This would be my last option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple thing just clear the adapter data and call notifyDataSetChanged of an adapter class each time you switch activity.

Comment: thanks! This tip is useful for me on another task.  Now my top priority is to find out why after running the testcase, a in A_Activity has been changed to refer the one in C_Activity.  I wrote my own Adapter based on SimpleAdapter and the list is declared private List **(non-static)**.

Answer (score 0):

Tab is started with 0. So start with 0.

tabhost.setCurrentTab(0);

1 means->0
 2 means->1
 and so on